# Detecting and preventing collusion in ratings

Tags: survey, rating

I am not sure whether or not this problem can be solved through statistical methods, but here is the problem:

I have 4 professional reference providers for a job candidate rating the candidate on a scale of 0-100 on say 10 items.  Behind the scenes we check for the consistency of ratings for each item from the 4 reference providers and arrive at a total score for each of the 10 items.

The problem is what is the 4 reference proviers collude with the candidate and give a rating of 100/100 on every item?  Such scores cannot be prevented because there may really be an excellent candidate who can score 100/100 on every item from each of the 4 reference providers.

So, is it possible to design a statistical method to differentiate between the fake candidate colluding with reference providers and the excellent candidate getting all 100 scores?

Comment: I would be very surprised if it could, absent other information that would be relevant to the ratings or to the collusion.

Comment: I can't imagine that there's really a way to objectively rate a job applicant on a 0-100 scale, let alone that you can account for the possibility that a referrer may give a higher or lower number than they actually believe to be true.

Comment: If you chose objective items and then anchor the scores on the item with specific examples (for example, if it's reading comprehension, the anchor for a score of 80 could be the ability to read and understand an arrticle in a technical journal), it is possible